# simple WSL winrm test

Tags: ansible, localhost

I'm trying to test ansible from my Ubuntu (WSL) instance.

I'm getting no where after following multiple guides. I've created a local user and added it to the admin and remote groups.

Here's my winrm config

```
PS C:\windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config/Service
Service
    RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
    MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
    MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
    EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
    MaxConnections = 300
    MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
    AllowUnencrypted = false [Source="GPO"]
    Auth
        Basic = false [Source="GPO"]
        Kerberos = true [Source="GPO"]
        Negotiate = true [Source="GPO"]
        Certificate = false
        CredSSP = false [Source="GPO"]
        CbtHardeningLevel = Strict [Source="GPO"]
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    IPv4Filter = * [Source="GPO"]
    IPv6Filter = * [Source="GPO"]
    EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false [Source="GPO"]
    EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false [Source="GPO"]
    CertificateThumbprint = 19 87 34 66 17 8b 17 4d  0e 0d 0b ff 28 5d 7b f1f6 d0 c8 10
    AllowRemoteAccess = true [Source="GPO"]

PS C:\windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config/WinRS
Winrs
    AllowRemoteShellAccess = true [Source="GPO"]
    IdleTimeout = 7200000
    MaxConcurrentUsers = 2 [Source="GPO"]
    MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
    MaxProcessesPerShell = 2000000000 [Source="GPO"]
    MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
    MaxShellsPerUser = 2000000000 [Source="GPO"]
```

inventory

```
[win]
192.168.1.2

[win:vars]
ansible_user=ansibleuser
ansible_password=strongpassword
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

And I'm calling this from Ubuntu (WSL)

```
ansible win -i inventory.ini -m win_ping
```

I get this

```
192.168.1.2 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "ntlm: the specified credentials were rejected by the server",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I'm able to logon [to windows] with those credentials so I know they are correct. I'm able to ping windows from Ubuntu. I also tried `ansible_user=ansiblesuer@<machine name>` to no avail.

Any ideas what to check?